# Margins in Dynamically Created Word Document

Tags: ms-word, word-2007

I have a piece of accountancy software that exports data into a Word document. I can create a specific template for each customer in Word 2007.

I need a way to set margins from the top of the page on all pages except the first.
The problem is I don't know in advance how many pages the document will be, but often between 1-3.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [tutorial](http://tortoiseshell.net/coffeebreak/blog/index.php/98/how-to-create-a-word-2007-template-that-has-different-first-page-margins.html).

I'll give the main steps here just in case but you'd better have a look at the link above:

**Set a Different First Page**

1. Start with a blank Word document.
2. Change the **Margins** (Page Layout tab, Page Setup group, Margins)
   to what the second page and following pages should be.
3. Choose **Edit Header**. (Insert tab, Header & Footer, Header, Edit
   Header)
4. In Header & Footer Tools, Design tab, Options, check **Different
   First Page**.

**Create the First Page Margins**

You are not really setting margins, you’re manipulating other Word features to act like margins.

**Top and Bottom Margins**

1. Go into the header or footer on the first page.
2. Change the top or bottom margins.

   - The quick way is to push your Enter key as many times as you need to
     create the distance for the margin spacing – turn on the Ruler and
     watch the left side ruler to get the distance close to what you want. Remember that by default the header or footer starts
     one-half inch from the edge of the page, so if you need a 2 inch top
     margin, the header will be 1.5 inches tall.
   - The more precise way would be to change the Paragraph Spacing (Home
     tab, Paragraph group, Paragraph dialog box). Paragraph Spacing
     appears measured in points, but you can type in 1″ or 1.5″ and Word
     will convert it to points for you (36 points is one-half inch, 72
     points is one inch, 144 points would be two inches). Set the After
     spacing to whatever distance you need. To increase the bottom margin,
     set the Before: paragraph spacing for the footer.

**Left and Right Margins**

If you need the left or right margins wider, insert a borderless, empty text box into the header of the first page. If you need both the left and right margins wider, you’ll add two text boxes, one for each side.

1. In the header on the first page, in the Insert tab, Text group, Text
   Box, **Draw Text Box**.
2. Click and drag to draw the text box from the header all the way down
   to the footer.
3. Right-click on the text box, choose **Format Text Box**. In the **Colors &
   Lines** tab, set the **Line Color** to none, to get rid of the border on
   the text box.
4. If you know you want the left margin to be two inches wide, go into
   the **Size** tab and set the **Text Box Width** to two inches. Position the
   text box at the very edge of the page and the text box will create
   the look of a two inch left margin.
5. In the Text Box Tools, Format tab, Arrange group, **Text Wrapping**, set
   the wrapping to **Square**.
6. If you need to change the right margin, could copy and paste the
   text box you just created, and move it to the right side of the
   page.
7. Close out of the header or footer on the first page.

Regards,